# Disable jQuery added by wordpress plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

I have a wordpress plugin which automatically adds jQuery "file" line to my website header, e.g.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wp-postratings-css'  href='http://domain.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-postratings/postratings-css.css?ver=1.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

I don't need this line because it refers to old version of jQuery plus I already have jQuery file included prior. I tried to disable following default wordpress functions "**wp_enqueue_script**", "**wp_print_scripts('jquery')**" but it didn't worked.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Seems to be a css file for some sort of ratings plugin. `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_print_scripts` have nothing to do with stylesheets. Have you tried simply disabling the plugin?

Comment: The problem is that I need this plugin enabled. I just don't need inclusion of old jQuery file in the website header.

Comment: No idea what you are doing. Explanation is not understandable so far

Answer (score 2):

if you add in your functions.php `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');` in essence this tells wordpress to load jQuery only once and will ignore any other instances.

to load your own jquery from an external source (example here is google)

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery', "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js", false, null);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

But wp_enqueue_script('jquery') will load jQuery file supplied by wordpress by its own(jQuery from wp-includes) while I want to load jQuery file from external source with my custom in website header